# Compute expectation when multiple vectors are involved

Tags: math, statistics, linear-algebra

From my understanding, the expectation of vector (let's say nx1) is equivalent to finding the mean. However if we have two vectors `x` and `y`, both of which are (nx1), what does it mean to try to find the expectation of the product of these vectors?

e.g:

```
E[x * y] = ?
```

Here are we taking the inner product or the outer product? If I was using Matlab, would I be doing:

```
E[x' * y]
```

or

```
E[x * y']
```

or

```
E[x .* y]
```

I'm not really understanding the intuition behind expectation as applied to the product of vectors (my background is not in mathematics), so if someone could shed light on this for me I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

== EDIT ==

You're right, I wasn't clear. I came across the definition of the covariance where the formula given was:

```
Cov[X; Y] = E[X * Y] - E[X] * E[Y]
```

And the part where `E[X * Y]` came up is what confused me. I should have put this up on a math site, and will next time. Thanks for the help.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on from @woodchips 's answer - when it does make sense to multiply two random variables and find the expectation of the product, in the discrete case it depends on whether you have the values for `X` and `Y` that correspond with each other i.e. if for each event you have an `x` and a `y`. In that case to find the expectation of the product, you simply multiply each pair of `x` and `y` you have and find the mean. If they're independent and you just have two vectors of samples and there is no co-occurrence, the expectation of the product is simply the product of their individual expectations.

Comment: Ok so then in the case it does make sense, when you say "multiply each pair of x and y" do you mean pair-wise multiplication (like `x .* y`)?

Comment: Yes, element-wise multiplication like that one.

Answer (score 2):

As much as I believe this belongs either on a math or statistics site, I'm feeling bored at the moment, so I'll say a few words.

YOU need to define when you are doing, and to understand what you want to see. Numbers, vectors, by themselves are all just that - numbers. There is no meaning without context. I'll argue this is your problem.

For example, you can view a vector as a list of numbers, thus samples from some distribution, but samples of a scalar valued parameter. Thus, my vector might be a list of the temperatures in my house over the course of a day, or of the rainfall for the last week. As such, we can talk about a mean of those measurements. If we had a distribution, we could talk about the expected value of that distribution.

You might also look at a vector as a SINGLE piece of information. It might represent my location on the surface of the earth, so perhaps [latitude, longitude, elevation]. As such, it makes no sense to take the mean of these three pieces of information. However, I might be interested in an average location, taken over many such location measurements over a period of time.

As far as worrying about inner versus outer products, they are confusing you. Instead, think about WHAT these numbers represent and what you need to do with them, and only THEN worry about how to compute what you need.